Compile C to "ELF, 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (GNU/Linux)", not "(SysV)"
how to convert .c to ELF, 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (GNU/Linux).  If i use this Command
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mabi=aapcs-linux -o output_file input_file.c

It become ELF, 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SysV)

Is there a practical problem you're encountering that led you to this question? (In general, Linux supports SysV ABI standards).

i want to compile .c to gnu/linux cause I'll put the file in router that using shell busybox

Yes, but do you have a problem running the SysV-ABI executable on that same router? If so, include that problem in the question.

yes, it didn't flash if sysv need gnu/linux. Im making firmware
